# Error on a line of code that has already been fixed

Tags: php, debugging, nette

When I run a `nette` app, I see an error on a line of code that doesn't exist anymore. Actually, I have changed that line of code but Tracy shows the code before changing it.

I tried removing `temp/cache` folder but it didn't fix the issue.

I'm running the app on my local machine using `php -S localhost:8000 -t www` command.

Comment: Tell Tracy to not do that

Answer (score 2):

temp/cache is only directory Nette uses for generated files and in debug mode generated DIC from nette/bootstrap and generated templates from nette/latte should always be reloaded on change. If removing that directory did not help, it's probably not Nette-related.

Ensure you actually saved the file and if you run the code on remote machine that it also uploaded successfully.

Also check your OPcache settings and Cache-Control and Pragma headers, content may be cached too aggresively.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. I'm running the app on my local machine using php -S localhost:8000 -t www command.

Answer (score 0):

There was a file with the same name in another module in the project. I was looking at the wrong file.